# Prove or disprove $(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)\leq(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, fake-proofs

Prove or disprove:

If $a, b, c \in (0, \infty)$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$ then
$$(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)\leq(a+b)(b+c)(c+a).$$

All my attempts to prove inequality have been unsuccessful. Maybe someone has an idea. Thank you very much!

Comment: There are several approaches one might take, but we need to know what tools you can use -- derivatives?  Trigonometric relations?  If you show at least some of the things you tried, we can tailor a solution.

Comment: I used simple means, AM-MG, C-B-S ... without derivatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's wrong! Try $c\rightarrow0^+$ and $a=b\rightarrow\sqrt{1.5}$